# Get log out time just before logging out

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a code to get username and writes it to a log file when you logout of wordpress but it has stopped working when i updated my wordpress core to 5.7.
When you log out the username is no longer written to the file. Maybe something wrong with my hook. This is my code:

```
        function get_username(){
         if(is_user_logged_in()){   
         $active_user = wp_get_current_user();           
         $username = $active_user->user_login;
         $username = "User's username: ".$username;
         log_file_setup($username);
         }
        }


      add_action('wp_logout', 'get_username',1);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? _"It has stopped working"_ is a vague description - you need to describe in which exact manner is the current behaviour different from the previous one.

Comment: I have a code to get username and writes it to a log file when you logout of wordpress but it has stopped working when i updated my wordpress core to 5.7.
When you log out the username is no longer written to the file. Maybe something wrong with my hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it

i changed the hook from:

```
 add_action( 'wp_logout', 'get_username', 1 );
```

to

```
  add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'get_username',1);
```

Any other suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear_auth_cookie` function to get username.

```
function users_last_login() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()){   
        $active_user = wp_get_current_user();           
        $username    = $active_user->user_login;
        $username    = "User's username: ".$username;
        update_user_meta( $active_user->ID, 'logout_time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
        log_file_setup($username);
    }
}
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', 'get_username_on_logout', 10 );
```

Or you can use `template_redirect`

```
function get_username_on_template_redirect() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'logout' && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $active_user = wp_get_current_user();           
        $username    = $active_user->user_login;
        $username    = "User's username: ".$username;
        update_user_meta( $active_user->ID, 'logout_time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
        log_file_setup($username);
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_username_on_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: I want to get the user name upon logging out